# What battery should I choose?

Tags: battery

Is there any battery that can fulfill the given requirements:

1. High energy output
2. Volume not more than approximately 9cm × 4cm × 2cm
3. Rechargeable (if rechargeable it's good, if not it's fine too)
4. Won't break or blast if dropped or used roughly

I searched for it and came up with lithium ion battery. It fulfills most of the above to some extent except being safe. Is there any better alternative?

Comment: For what are you planning to use it?

Comment: voltage and current requirements would be necessary for a proper recommendation. Look for LiFePO4 if you want safe(r), but the volts and amps are important, as well as capacity (Ahr)